# Know the MAC address in the network without touching the router

Tags: networking, router, mac-address

I'm new to network programming and I don't know if this is the right place where to ask.

I have a small router with a proprietary control panel (= no openwrt or similar). I'd like to know programmatically what are the MAC addresses connected to the router.

Is it possible?

Comment: I remember some routers export this information via SNMP.

Comment: Use `nmap` and scan your local subnet. Or maybe all private subnets. Since you don’t have to operate stealthily, a full-speed scan is possible. If you already have the IP addresses, just `arp` them.

Comment: @DanielB ARP would do it but  if arp doesn't have the IPs, then i'd be surprised if nmap can scan his local subnet. OTOH I suppose nmap could help trigger an ARP request. But in that case, pinging every ip on a subnet would also be effective at filling the arp table

Comment: `nmap` has built-in optimizations for host discovery, including so-called ARP Pinging (`-RP`). In this case, `nmap` itself generates ARP requests and collects responses. It’s much faster than letting the OS handle it.

Answer (score 0):

As @grawity said check if in the config there is SNMP settings.

The other option would be to use something like http://casperjs.org/ to scrap the arp table it lists.

Or run a sniffer and watch for ARP requests with the IP of the router.